# Must I retro-actively DCO-sign my sole author commits for a work project?

Tags: contributor-agreements, developer-certificate-of-origin

I am currently the sole author of a codebase, created for my employer, released under AGPL 3 or later. Moving forward, I want to require that contributions are signed, following the [Developer Certificate of Origin](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/dco) convention.

To date I have not signed commits myself. Do I need to retroactively sign my old commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the sole author my "unsigned" commits follow whatever agreement I currently have with my employer. If it is my employer, not me, who will be in a position to legally defend the code, there is no strict need to sign the old commits. (And, as pointed out by Amon, [old commits are probably covered by any current signature](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/6711/1082). In the worst case, I can [retroactively sign the hashes via a text file](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/6722/1082), as suggested by the Linux Foundation, if the need arose.

Answer (score 4):

First, consider why you want to mandate signed commits. They are not a best practice for most open-source projects because they represent a significant barrier to entry – you need to set up GPG, manage a key-ring, and exchange public keys so that they can be verified. Signed commits have most value when

- the software is security-sensitive, so you want to be able to tie all contributions to a committer, or
- the project is likely to be under legal threat, so you want to be able to trace every contribution to an author that has understood and agreed to the licensing and to the Developer Certificate of Origin. The project can then demonstrate through all signatures that they have exercised due diligence.

E.g. for the Linux Kernel project, both of these considerations apply.

If you are only interested in the potential legal benefits and manage development through GitHub, there are less cumbersome third-party solutions that verify only that the user account of a pull request has signed a DCO. This is a weaker guarantee than signed commits and represents some platform lock-in, but is much more contributor-friendly.

If you have decided that commit signatures are desirable, then you should only sign the most recent commit, and then sign all new commits afterwards. This is because of the Git data model:

- All data of a commit is hashed to produce an identifier for the commit.
- A commit includes the IDs of parent commits.
- When a commit is signed, the signature is part of the commit.

So if you were to sign an existing commit, its ID would change and you would have to re-write your complete history. But signing old commits is not necessary since the commit references parent commits – so you're not really signing an individual change, but the complete Git history up to and including that change.

Comment: as far as I'm aware cryptographic signatures are not required: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6716

Comment: This answer confuses PGP signing with DCO sign-off. These are different.

Answer (score 0):

Response from the Linux Foundation:

> Most projects that implement the DCO after being in development without it start by first requiring it for all future commits. Some will then go back to contributors and get a signed-off-by for their prior commits in a simple text file they check into git with the various commit hashes of their contributions (usually in a docs folder).