# Does the DCO require a cryptographic signature?

Tags: contributor-agreements, developer-certificate-of-origin

The [Developer Certificate of Origin](https://developercertificate.org/) mentions a signature:

> I understand and agree that this project and the contribution are public and that a record of the contribution (including all personal information I submit with it, including my sign-off...

Does this mean a cryptographic (GPG) signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically all you need is a text signature, which you can achieve with:

```
git commit -s
```

However, the signing mechanism is not defined by the DCO, but by the project. Some projects may ask for a cryptographic signature, others may ask that you use your work-based email (if submitting from work), others may ask that you send an email, or some combination.

This is based a determination by the project balancing ease-of-use and legal risk. (Similarly to a CLA.)

> The DCO uses a common law technique called agency by which a person can act on behalf of an entity like a corporation... using a corporate email as a developer is [an example of] such a sign of authority. (James Bottomley, [A modest proposal on the DCO](https://blog.hansenpartnership.com/a-modest-proposal-on-the-dco/))

**References:**

- https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/dco
- https://julien.ponge.org/blog/developer-certificate-of-origin-versus-contributor-license-agreements/ (includes suggestion for cryptographic signatures as further mitigation, but references text sign-off as a common practice)

**Examples:**

- [PyBee contribution instructions](https://pybee.org/contributing/how/dco/what/)
- [GitLab CONTRIBUTING.md](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) (see also [GitLab Case Study](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/6721/1082) for some legal analysis)
- [Samba copyright policy](https://www.samba.org/samba/devel/copyright-policy.html)

Comment: The `Signed-off-by` metadata is only marginally more useful than the commit author. It is unlikely that this sign-off would be considered to be a legally binding signature, as it cannot be used to verify the _identity_ of the signatory. It can also be faked easily, since it's not cryptographic. This metadata may be helpful for review workflows, but has minimal value as a reliable record of DCO acceptance.

Comment: @amon It's odd, because every reference (that I can find) treats it as valid. Despite underlining the fact that it's just text. Cargo cult practice?

Comment: @amon Problem solved (I think), it's a per-project decision, not determined by the DCO itself - I found claims that even using cryptographic signatures is cargo cultish :P so this is obviously one of those things - the GitLab case study link highlights their legal assessment of text-signatures only